# Error:defalut skin class null :: while adding Spark List to Mx ViewStack

Tags: apache-flex, rsl, flex-mx, flex-spark

Also tried adding it List in  `NavigatorContent` Class. Still the Default Skin of the spark List goes null when i assign the dataprovider and hence i get a error.

Now for the background i am using a Custom Tree which extends Spark List in a Legacy Project which uses all Mx components.

Its a project with many Library projects using RSL settings. using SDK 4.6.

This is the code where spark tree is added.

```
<skins:VBox left="5" top="5" right="15" verticalGap="1" id="topBox">
            <skins:HBox id="topBar" width="100%">
                <skins:Label id="titleLabel" text="{this._headerText}"
                             styleName="leftPanelPopUpTitleLabel" />
                <skins:Spacer width="100%" />
                <skins:LinkButton label="Cancel" click="this.close();"
                                  styleName="linkButtonStyle" />
            </skins:HBox>
            <skins:Label id="featureName"
                         text="{this._feature.getNameFromDdctType()}"
                         styleName="labelID" />
            <skins:Label id="featureID" text="{this._feature.getId()}"
                         styleName="leftPanelPopUpTitleLabel" />
        </skins:VBox>

        <skins:VBox id="treeBox" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
                    top="{topBox.height+5}" height="{topBar.height + 5}">
            <skins:HBox id="dropBox" left="5" top="30" right="15">
                <skins:ComboBox id="itemsToAdd" selectedIndex="0" />
                <skins:Button id="clickToAdd" label="Add"
                              click="addParentAttributeNode()" />
            </skins:HBox>
            **<sparkTree:Tree id="attributesTree" width="100%" height="100%"
                            indentation="15" />**
            <!-- Bottom Gray Box starts-->
            <skins:VBox backgroundColor="#EBEBEB" height="68" width="100%"
                        bottom="0" verticalGap="5" paddingTop="3" paddingRight="5"
                        paddingLeft="5" paddingBottom="3">
                <skins:HBox horizontalGap="5" width="100%">
                    <skins:LinkButton id="templatesButton" label="SelectedTemplate"
                                      styleName="linkButtonStyle" width="95" />
                    <skins:InvisibleCanvas height="20" width="2">
                        <skins:Image 
                                     source="@Embed(source='Images/vertical-separator.png')" />
                    </skins:InvisibleCanvas>
                    <skins:LinkButton id="applyTemplateButton"
                                      label="Apply template"
                                      styleName="linkButtonStyle" width="95" />
                    <skins:InvisibleCanvas height="20" width="2">
                        <skins:Image 
                                     source="@Embed(source='Images/vertical-separator.png')" />
                    </skins:InvisibleCanvas>
                    <skins:LinkButton id="editTemplatesButton"
                                      label="Template Editor"
                                      styleName="linkButtonStyle" width="95" />
                </skins:HBox>
                <skins:HRule width="100%" strokeColor="#FFFFFF" />
                <skins:HBox horizontalGap="8" width="100%">
                    <skins:ColoredButton id="OkButton" label="OK" />
                    <skins:ColoredButton id="cancelButton" label="Cancel"
                                         fillColor="0xcc3333" />
                    <skins:Button id="applyButton" label="Apply"
                                  click="applyChanges()" />
                    <skins:Spacer width="100%" />
                    <skins:HBox id="copyPasteHBox" horizontalGap="0"
                                paddingRight="9" backgroundAlpha="0"
                                disabledOverlayAlpha="0">
                        <skins:Button height="23" width="20" skin='{null}'
                                      toolTip="Copy" id="btnCopy"
                                      chromeColor="#E4E4E4" />
                        <skins:Button height="23" width="20" skin='{null}'
                                      paddingLeft="15" toolTip="Paste" id="btnPaste"
                                      tabEnabled="false" tabFocusEnabled="false"
                                      enabled="false" />
                    </skins:HBox>
                </skins:HBox>
            </skins:VBox>
            <!-- Bottom Gray Box ends-->
        </skins:VBox>

    </skins:Canvas>
```

Also its added in as3  using this.viewstack.addChild(component).
can it be  that the sparkskins.swc is not properly attched to the plugin.If yes how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

We need more details (codes, log..) to help you with this!

First, you can't add a List component in ViewStack, you must add the list in a NavigatorContent first, look at this example:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack"
              width="100%" 
              height="100%"
              creationPolicy="auto">

    <s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:List height="100%"
                width="100%"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>

    <s:NavigatorContent>
        ...
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    ...
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Then, for the null pointer exception, it can be caused by a missing swc lib at runtime, so to be sure disable RSLs feature from your project setting panel then try again.

If the error persist, share your bug codes, so we can test with you.

Comment: I cannot remove RSL's coz that would greatly increase the final application's size. I have a case where the Spark  List is added into a heirarchy of Mx components namely VBox,Canvas etc. before getting added to the Viewstack.  i will add Details as u requested...Thnx for replying